# Non-updating socket message

Tags: java, android, c++, sockets

I've been working on a connection between my Raspberry Pi and my phone and to accomplish it, I want to use sockets.
With my minimal amount of experience, I sniffed around the internet in an attempt to find socket code for my Pi (C++) and an Android app for my phone (Java). Both are included below.

The problem I run into is the fact that the textbox on my phone doesn't update when a new message is sent from the C++ server. I believe that the code I wrote in C++ is fine. All it has to do is keep asking the user for new input to send over to the clients.

I believe the problem is to be founnd in the Java app for my phone.

I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing and I hope someone here can explain me what's happening (or rather what isn't happening) in simple terms.

Thank you in advance!

C++ Server code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio;
using ip::tcp;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

string read_(tcp::socket & socket)
{
boost::asio::streambuf buf;
boost::asio::read_until(socket, buf, "\n" );
string data = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(buf.data());
return data;
}

void send_(tcp::socket & socket, const string& message)
{
const string msg = message + "\n";
boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(message));
}

int main()
{
boost::asio::io_service io_service;

tcp::acceptor acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 41517));

tcp::socket socket_(io_service);

acceptor_.accept(socket_);
/*
string message = read_(socket_);
cout << message << endl;
*/
send_(socket_, "Hello from server!\n");
cout << "Server sent hello message to Client!" << endl;

char message[400];

while(true)
{
std::cin.getline(message, 400);
string messageStr = message;

if(messageStr.length() > 0)
{
send_(socket_, messageStr);
cout << "The following message has been sent:" << endl << endl;
cout << messageStr << endl << endl << "-----------------------------" << endl << endl;
}

else
{
cout << "No message has been sent." << endl << endl << "-----------------------------" << endl << endl;
}
}

return 0;
}
```

Java client code

```
package com.example.socket_test2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.SocketAddress;

import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView responseField;
    EditText ipField, portField;
    Button randomButton;

    ConnectionMaker juin = new ConnectionMaker();

    Socket sock = new Socket();

    BufferedReader br;

    private class ConnectionMaker extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {
        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... strings) {

            try {
                SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(strings[0], parseInt(strings[1]));
                sock.connect(addr);

                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));

                while(true) {
                    responseField.setText(br.readLine());
                }

                //sock.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                responseField.setText(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            }



            return 1;
        }
    }

    View.OnClickListener action = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
                juin.execute(ipField.getText().toString(), portField.getText().toString());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                responseField.setText(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        responseField = findViewById(R.id.ResponseField);
        randomButton = findViewById(R.id.RandomButton);

        ipField = findViewById(R.id.IP_Field);
        portField = findViewById(R.id.Port_Field);

        randomButton.setOnClickListener(action);
    }
}
```

Comment: `send_(socket_, messageStr);` That should be `send_(socket_, messageStr+"\n");`  The client tries to read lines so server should send lines.

Comment: Even when the send_() function has +"\n"?

Comment: No. Sorry, oversaw that.

Comment: Your client is only reading lines. Not sending any lines to the server.  Only the first line sent by the server comes in. Further the server does not send any line. Only if the server disconnects a null line will be read by the client.

Comment: So the while(true) loop of the server never sends a line.

Comment: Which is why the \n (which got all of this to work!!) is necessary?

Comment: Thanks a bunch, @blackapps!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `doInBackground` method of `AsyncTask` does not run on the UI thread, so you are not allowed to call `responseField.setText` there. Or rather: you can call it but it is not guaranteed to be seen by the UI thread.

Instead, use `publishProgress`, whose `onProgressUpdate` handler is called on the UI thread:

```
private class ConnectionMaker extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... strings) {

        try {
            SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(strings[0], parseInt(strings[1]));
            sock.connect(addr);

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));

            while(true) {
                publishProgress(br.readLine());
            }

            //sock.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            responseField.setText(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        responseField.setText(progres[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried implementing your solution, but it did not work. I did, however, find that whenever I stop my C++ code, the textbox is emptied. Do you have any idea what that could mean?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this helped in fixing the problem or not, but I'd like to express my gratitude anyway! Thank you for helping @Botje!